# How to protect SharePoint Document (Read only and not allow to download)

Tags: sharepoint

In some case , I need to upload some documents to the SharePoint library , other user can read the document , but I dont expect the user can be download it .

Is it available to make the setting , the Document Library is not allow to download , only read..

Thanks.

Platform :SharePoint 2010 , SharePoint 2013

Comment: If they can read it, like for example with Word, then they have the option to save it on their pc ... so I don't think removing the option to download will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Applying information rights management might help you achieve this. Have a look at the following link

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/apply-information-rights-management-to-a-list-or-library-HA101790603.aspx

Comment: For the IRM , I think its not working for my case , cos its only support of Microsoft file (Word , Excel etc.). How about PDF , Image ??

Answer (score 1):

You can force the document to be read-only by clicking check out option. But you cant restrict user from download it and edit by using save as option.

Comment: We have whatever sharepoint comes with office 365, but there seems to be no checkout option, and no way to make a file read only. This is a showstopper for using 365.